# In Notepad++ I'm doing a lot of editing..with ADHD. Is there an app or setting or box that will list for me the edits I have made?

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, xml

I think the title covers all - basically I'm after a "this is the changes you've made" box. I guess kind of a compare tool, except I no longer have the original to compare to!

I have really bad ADHD and I lose track of edits I'm making in the files I'm currently working on (plus this coding is a new thing for me so I'm not even sure what I'm doing most of the time) and it's pretty stressful seeing a red icon and not even remembering editing that file!

Comment: "it's pretty stressful seeing a red icon and not even remembering editing that file!" - Use commentary to remind yourself of the updates and when they were done.

Comment: Another approach is to (a) ensure a backup of the original file, (b) edit the existing file as needed,  (c) save and compare to the backup. That will identify the changes.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly one of the purposes of [version control / source control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) systems. Originally developed for source code, they do this so well that people even use it for other projects / documents. Human readable document formats profit the most, but that's exactly what you are doing in Notepad++.

I use [Git](https://git-scm.com/), which is command line based, but it's supported by many programs with a GUI (e.g. [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)). (Both are free and available for many operating systems.)

Comment: The SVN client [TortoiseSVN](https://osdn.net/projects/tortoisesvn/) can allow you to create a local filesystem based repository and includes tools to diff files and integrates nicely into the Windows right-click menu system for ease of use. I would assume [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/) has similar features and would be a similarly good alternative.